# Изменение значения каждые 4 часа, после предыдущего изменения

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть в таблице `users` строка `hour`, по умолчанию значение = 0.

После выполнения функции значение `hour` становиться равно 1

Как сделать так что-бы, через 4 часа после того как значение стало 1, оно снова изменялось на 0?

Comment: Лучше использовать не поле со значениями 0 и 1, а писать в запись дату/время последнего выполнения операции. Тогда легко будет проверить что уже прошли 4 часа `hour < now()-interval 4 hour`

Comment: Не очень понял что за код в конце, можно подробнее?

Comment: ну это часть или where или самого select. в зависимости от желаемого эффекта. сравнивайте поле с текущей датой - 4 часа например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю Вы хотите сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог выполнять какую-то функцию раз в 4 часа, можно сделать так:
После выполнения функции мы заносим (текущее время + нужный нам интервал времени (в данном случае 60*60*4 секунд) `time() + 14400` в базу данных и при попытке вызова этой функции сравниваем время `time`, если текущее время меньше, чем время, которое в таблице, то мы отказываем в выполнении.

Comment: Не очень разбираюсь в php и mysql)
Если не сложно, мог бы написать это сразу готовым кодом?

Comment: Вот принцип, Вам нужно только разобраться с выбором значения из БД и вашей функцией
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d80cc6ad11aa26f73f1748dda703ff279d323c43

Comment: @nameisusselesinfo Не надо хранить время в БД в секундах. его надо хранить всегда в виде datetime. Тогда не надо будет высчитывать секунды, а можно будет по человечески писать `now() + interval 4 hour` вместо time() + 14400, вдобавок MySQL сделает это гораздо эффективнее, чем php